# How to get 720p Android Camera Preview Data?

Tags: android, resolution, android-camera, preview

I want to use the camera preview for image recognition. For my
purposes, I need the preview resolution to be as high as possible
(and, at the same time, display the preview to the user).

I created a Preview class, extending SurfaceView and set the
PreviewSize to 1280x720. I added a PreviewCallBack to get the live
Image:

```
camera = Camera.open();

parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewSize(1280,720);

camera.setParameters( parameters);
byte[] b = new byte[camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width *
  camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height *
  ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat()) / 8];
camera.addCallbackBuffer(b);
camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new CameraPreviewCallback());

try {
 camera.setPreviewDisplay(this.getHolder());
 camera.startPreview()
}
```

My Byte Array b is 1382400 Byte and my
CameraPreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame() function receives those 1382400
Bytes - but only the first 497664 Byte contain data (matching a
768x432 resolution (HTC Desire)).

I tested this on different devices, all with display resolutions of
800x480 (HTC Desire, LG Optimus 3D, Samsung Galaxy S2, Samsung Galaxy
Tab, ...). The only device my Code works for is a HTC Desire HD.

Does anyone know how to receive the full 720p resolution as a Byte
Array?
"Something" seems to reduce the preview resolution to fit the smartphone display.

Regards

Joern

Comment: Are you sure that your phone supports 720p? Does Logcat say anything (like "can't set resolution")?

Comment: Yep, 720p is supported on all devices as preview size. Logcat does not say anything special - it looks like "something" reduces the preview resolution silently.

Comment: Does getPreviewSize() return the correct size?

Comment: Just tested this on my desire, can verify this. The preview size is supported and works, but the returned preview data is smaller as described here. Very weird.

Answer (score 8):

You can't use any random resolution for a camera preview.

Certain devices only support certain resolutions. You can query these via [`Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29)¹. If your device doesn't return `1280x720` in this list, you can't use it. Select a supported resolution that comes close to your desired one instead.

¹ *You should do so in general before using any resolution, 720p or not*

Comment: (Unfortunately) 1280x720p is in the list of every listed device. I checked the SupportedPreviewSizes.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, the answer is unchanged: the list of supported preview sizes for each device is not accurate.  The default preview size is, to the best of my knowledge, always valid.  Other sizes appear to work at most on a case-by-case basis - you can be reasonably confident that a default preview size won't look *incorrect* on screen, but that's all.  In particular, that Byte Array won't scale to accommodate larger image formats even if they're "supported", and only some of the "supported" preview sizes will be properly rendered at-resolution and without green/pink distortion.

The only reliable way to know that the resolution is correct and the data from onPreviewFrame() is good is to test this manually.